# Conflicting peer dependency: React Native for iOS

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

When I attempt to build react native program following its official website guideline on Mac, it gives me the following errors. Any suggestions about debugging?

> npx react-native init A2 Need to install the following packages:
> react-native@0.69.0 Ok to proceed? (y) y npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm
> ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve npm ERR!  npm ERR! While resolving:
> undefined@undefined npm ERR! Found: react-native@0.68.2 npm ERR!
> node_modules/react-native npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from
> @react-native-community/cli@7.0.3 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@react-native-community/cli npm ERR!
> @react-native-community/cli@"^7.0.3" from react-native@0.68.2 npm ERR!
> react-native@"0.69.0" from the root project npm ERR!  npm ERR! Could
> not resolve dependency: npm ERR! react-native@"0.69.0" from the root
> project npm ERR!  npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.0.0
> npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!   peer react@"18.0.0" from
> react-native@0.69.0 npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native npm ERR!
> react-native@"0.69.0" from the root project npm ERR!  npm ERR! Fix the
> upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with
> --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR!  npm ERR! See
> /Users/student/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/student/.npm/_logs/2022-06-25T16_09_36_906Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Did you try this ```retry npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps``` as is mentioned in the error logs ?
```npm install --legacy-peer-deps```

Comment: Do you mean typing in command: "retry npm ERR! --force" or "retry npm ERR! --legacy-peer-deps"? I tried both and the console said "command not found: retry". I attempted to fix it with "brew install retry" but it doesn't help. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: ```npm install --legacy-peer-deps``` is what I wanted you to try.

Comment: That command reports me "up to date, audited 1 package in 174ms, found 0 vulnerabilities." But I still can't run the program.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with peer dependency on the latest node version. This command should solve the problem: `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`. Take a look on  this issue for reference: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34051#issuecomment-1198463785